# ASP.NET MVC5 file download security best practices?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security

We are building an ASP.NET MVC5 web app which includes serving file downloads.

Users are required to login using ASP.NET Identity framework.

The files are stored in the database (we are interfacing with a legacy application) and each file is identified by a standard integer primary key.

We plan to serve the files as follows:

1. The user requests a file using its ID eg. `http://www.example.com/getFile?fileId=5`
2. The controller then checks to see if the requesting user is allowed to access that file (using some complex business rules) and if successful streams the file to the user.

I have been researching best practices but am struggling to find specifics as most of what I've read deals with the scenario where the files are being read from physical paths and therefore the recommendation is to obfuscate the filename in the request.

We *could* obfuscate the file's ID but I don't see much point to that if the controller will validate the user's access to the file on each request.

**Is our approach sufficient or should we be doing it another way, if so, what is the recommended way please?**

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is perfectly sufficient. If your authorisation rules in your controller adequately protect the files, then this should be all that you require.

The only information leak that is occurring is the use of what is presumably the primary key of the file in the database in the URL that is being used to request the file. This could potentially create a vulnerability if for example another part of your application is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks and an attacker makes use of the IDs in your URL to construct a SQL injection attack to fetch a file with a specific ID. Whether this is a risk in practice however depends on whether your application is also vulnerable to SQL injection attacks and most attackers would probably guess or brute force the IDs any way, so there may be little practical benefit to masking these even if you were vulnerable to SQL injection attacks - a better focus in that case would be to simply make sure that you're not.

Answer (score -1):

I've once created something similar.

The user asked for a file, we validated if the user could access the file and then streamed it to their browser. 
One thing we did though, is store the files outside of the web app folder. This made sure that the files couldn't get into Google by accident, and is also more secure, because malevolent users can't use the full path to the file to download the file directly.

You can obfuscate the file name quite easily. Take a look at this code for example:

```
 public FileResult Download()
 {
    byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\folder\myfile.ext");
    string fileName = "myfile.ext";
    return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
 }
```

in the variable "filename", you put the file that the user will get to see. This can be anything.

Hope this helps.

Comment: -1 using `byte[]` can cause memory fragmentations. "Obfuscation" of the "file name" is irrelevant, as the is no file name, since data is stored in the database. The URL continues to contain the file name... Not all browsers will honour the file name.